# jQuery Ajax - Can query string parameters be set separately from the request body?

Tags: jquery

If you want to set the query string separately from the request body, it seems the only way is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url.com?' + "id=" + id,
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

    }
});
```

Is there an alternative way? Just trying to avoid typos, etc. when setting the url.

Comment: I think you have a typo. You want the "request body separate from the request body"?

Comment: On a POST they can be different. On a GET, they are the same.

Comment: I think you have found the only way but it only works on a POST.

Answer (score 0):

When it's a POST then you set it as DATA block which is added to request's header. In a GET request it's embedded inside request string. Nevertheless you can make use of `$.ajaxSetup` but it's not recommended to have a default request string.

Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Comment: Even with $.ajaxSetup, if you specify data, then it will be overridden with the data in $.ajax

Comment: That's right. I thought you want to have default address, where you send every request. If you customize your address on every request ajaxSetup won't be much of help